# Disable HDMI port on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pi-3b+, hdmi, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on an RPI 3 B+, and I would like to disable HDMI to conserve power.

tvservice seems to be missing, is there any way to do this if I'm not running raspbian?

Comment: You could try asking in the AskUbuntu (https://askubuntu.com/) or Unix (https://unix.stackexchange.com/) Forum.

Comment: I have decided to just switch to raspbian but the question is still up in the air

Comment: You should edit your question and the title to reflect the new situation with using RaspiOS.